# can someone help me make sense of this solution? (finite fields)

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

solve the equation $8x+7 = 5$ in the field $(\mathbb{Z}_{11}, +, \cdot)$
solution $$8x+7=5$$
$$8x=5+(-7)$$
$$8x=-2$$
$$8x=9$$

since 7 is the multiplicative inverse of 8, multiply both sides by 7

$$x=63=8$$

the solution is $$x=8$$

$$8 \cdot 8 +7 = 71 =5$$

im having alot of trouble understanding finite fields, can someone please explain how $8x=-2$ turned into $8x=9$? and i dont understand why $8 \cdot 8+7=71=5$

Comment: You are in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, whose elements are the remainders of integers, modulo $11$. In particular, $-2$ and $9$ are equivalent (leave the same remainder) modulo $11$

Comment: Similarly, modulo $11$, we have $$71\equiv 71-6\cdot 11\equiv 5\pmod{11}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the world of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, $11$ is equivalent to $0$.

$$8x = -2 = 0-2 =11-2 = 9$$

$$71 = 6(11)+5=6(0)+5=5$$

More formally,

$$8x \equiv -2 \equiv 0-2 \equiv 11-2 \equiv 9 \pmod{11}$$

$$71 \equiv 6(11)+5 \equiv6(0)+5 \equiv5 \pmod{11}$$

We say two numbers are equivalent $\mod{11}$ if $a-b$ is divisible by $11$.